# How to limit a decimal number?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697977/how-to-format-a-decimal)

How can I limit my decimal number so I'll get only 3 digits after the point?

```
e.g  2.774
```

Comment: for display? or to lose precision even more than you do already with floating point...?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[Math.Round Method (Decimal, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx)

**Example:**

```
Math.Round(3.44, 1); //Returns 3.4.
```

Comment: Note that by default, C# uses "Banker's Rounding" which may not be what you want, so there is a method overload Math.Round(decimal, int, MidpointRounding) to let you specify exactly which rounding method to use.  E.g. TSQL uses 'Away From Zero' rounding so may give a different value than default C# rounding.

Answer (score 15):

I'm assuming you really mean formatting it for output:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.###}", value);
```

Comment: You can also use a [format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-fixed-point-f-format-specifier): `string result = 1.23456.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 8):

To get Decimal back use `Math.Round` with Second parameter specifying number of decimal points.

```
decimal d = 54.9700M;    
decimal f = (Math.Round(d, 2)); // 54.97
```

To Get String representation of number use `.ToString()` Specifiying Decimal Points as N3. Where 3 is the decimal points

```
decimal d = 54.9700M;    
string s = number.ToString("N3"); // "54.97"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.Round` to round it to **3** decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Limiting the precision of a floating point number is a SQL concept.  Decimal in csharp only means that it will remember the precision assigned.  You can round to three decimal places before assigning.  IE, `Math.Round()`.

Answer (score 0):

Part of my answer is the response, another part is just a interesting point:

I often want to see the variable as a `prop/field`. So a create a `extension method` to solve my problem:

Tensao is just an Enum that have a value related.

```
    public static class TensaoExtensions {
        public static double TensaoNominal(this Tensao tensao) {
            return Math.Round((double.Parse(EnumMapper.Convert(typeof(Tensao),
                           tensao.ToString()))) * 1000 / Math.Sqrt(3), 3);
        }
    }
```