# How to limit a decimal in an ASP.NET MVC Model

Tags: model, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on creating a Model called Employee_Wage and it has a field named HourlyWage.  I would like to set this to decimal(4, 2) in the database, but I'm unsure how to do this and I haven't found any documentation when searching on how to do this.

When the table is created by default the data type of HourlyWage is decimal(18, 2).  I do not want this behavior.

Similar post that doesn't answer what I am trying to do:
[How to limit a decimal number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212491/how-to-limit-a-decimal-number)

Comment: I assume you mean via code first? - if so,refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504660/decimal-precision-and-scale-in-ef-code-first)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that is exactly what I needed, thank you!