# How can I format a decimal?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697977/how-to-format-a-decimal)

I need to format a decimal like the following:

```
63.000 -> 63
63.045 -> 63.045
63.020 -> 63.02
```

But look at above, check the first one, if in decimal part there are only zeros, I need to remove those zeros for just 63.

Comment: I have tried several string formats, but I didn't find any one

Comment: try `number.ToString("0.###")`

Answer (score 0):

String.Format would work for you, and the pattern `"{0:0.###}"` would work for all 3 of your cases.

```
String.Format("{0:0}", 63.000); 
String.Format("{0:0.###}", 63.045); 
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 63.02);
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head,

```
string.Format("{0:0.###}");
```

Answer (score 0):

// max. three decimal places

```
String.Format("{0:0.###}", 63.000);      // "63"
String.Format("{0:0.###}", 63.045);         // "63.045"
String.Format("{0:0.###}", 63.02);         // "63.02"
```